# Passing device pointers through host objects

Tags: c++, cuda

I am trying to offload parts of my c++ code to GPUs so I wrote a wrapper file `wrapper.cu"` that does all the cuda stuff and is compiled with nvcc while I call those functions to my c++ code written in g++. I want to store the device pointers as member variables of a class so I can pass it around to various kernels but I am having trouble with copying arrays that are initialized at a host class to devices.

```
//wrapper.cu
//simple func to copy arrays from host to device
void cuda_h2d(int* src, int* dst, int size)
{
    cudaMalloc(&dst, size*sizeof(int));
    cudaMemcpy(dst, src, size*sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

This function is called in my cpp code like:

```
//main.cpp
.
.

Class obj; //object that has a pointer to respective device array as a member(int* device_array)
int host_array[3] = {2,3,4};
int size = 3;
cuda_h2d(host_array, obj.device_array, size);
```

When I access the values of `obj.device_array` in another host function, it gives garbage values. So my assumption is that the pointer to the device array cannot be initialised in host code. How do I work around this. I know using `CudaMallocManaged()` from Cuda unified memory will work but I am trying to do without that for various performance constraints.

Comment: "So my assumption is that the pointer to the device array cannot be initialised in host code" -- that is false. Beyond that, an actual working example would be necessary to say more. I will guess that your issue is actually related to class copy construction semantics and destructors being called when you don't want them to, but it is impossible to say

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in `cuda_h2d` and has nothing to do with CUDA itself.

Indeed, `cudaMalloc` allocate a memory block and put it in `dst`, then `cudaMemcpy` performs the copy and then the function return. When the function `cuda_h2d` return, `obj.device_array` is not modified because the parameter **`dst` is passed by value**.

You need to pass the `dst` pointer by reference or use a pointer-to-pointer like `cudaMalloc` does to actually modify the pointer at the calling scope.